# What does "tell us know what you think" mean?

Tags: grammaticality, meaning-in-context

Is it even grammatical? A little bit of [Googling](http://www.google.com.sg/search?q=%22Tell%20Us%20Know%20What%20You%20Think%22) returns quite a number of searches which lead me to think it is a grammatical sentence.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe how often that phrase turns up!

Comment: When I search it *verbatim* now, this page is the second rank.

Comment: @kojiro Google is fast. Now it's the first!

Comment: It's merely a case of one typo of '**let** us know...'/'tell us **now**...', repeatedly copy-pasted by as many enthusiasts as the number turns up in Google search.

Comment: Potential idiom!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

All the links you cite should have been either "Tell us what you think" or "Let us know what you think" (one of them even has the correct title, but is wrong in the first sentence). Getting confused, and ending up halfway between the two, is not uncommon, but it is not right.  (In my opinion, it never will be right no matter how often it is used: but it is definitely wrong now).

Comment: +1 Most likely an artefact of typing one, then editing to the other, but getting distracted, not doing it properly, then not proofreading.

Comment: @slim Or just as likely, proofreading and not seeing the mistake, since you expect it to be fixed...

Answer (score 14):

This is an error. Probably the writers of this phrase have in mind the common phrases

> *tell us* what you think

and

> *let us know* what you think

and simply mix them up.

Answer (score 8):

“Tell us know what you think” is not grammatical. The first three words are the problem: You can’t do “VP VP” in English (VP=Verb Phrase). The Google link shows lots of instances, but it is not at all grammatical.

Most likely it is a very easy typo to mistakenly write “know” for “now”.

The following sentence is probably what was intended in all those cases.

> Tell us *now* what you think.

Comment: I disagree with now -> know, it seems more likely (since it's the idiom) that they've changed *let* to *tell*.

Comment: @Matt Эллен: I guess it also depends whether they are native speaker or not. I have seen know->now swapped several times.

Answer (score 5):

It is not grammatical as written;  assuming it’s not an internet meme of some sort, I can only presume that it was intended to be “Let us know what you think”, but somebody typo’ed “Let” into “Tel” and then the spell-checker corrected from “Tel” to “Tell”.

Comment: +1 for spell-checker auto-"correcting" to a grammatically incorrect sentence.  That's exactly how I would assume such a sentence would come about.  Except in cases where the author has read someone else's mistake elsewhere and thinks it means something.. :D

Answer (score 2):

Tell us know what you think
Let us know what you think ←
Tell us now what you think ←
Let us now what you think

The second and the third ones are meaningful.